# Wix installer is blank or disabled on windows 10

Tags: wix, windows-installer, windows-10, wix3.8

Wix installer .msi is totally disabled (blank) if i run it on windows 10, but on all other versions of windows it is working fine.
Is there anything that should be added in order to recognize Win 10, or some update...?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed this condition while there version for windows 10 is different and it is working now....

```
<Condition Level="0">
        <![CDATA[NOT IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6"]]>
      </Condition>
```

Comment: Expanding on that....  Conditional Statement syntax in MSI evaluates from MSI and thinks that 10 is less then 6 because 1 is less then 6.  Your conditional expression needs to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it.